# WIndows Forms dynamic layout

Tags: winforms, layout, tablelayoutpanel

I have a custom usercontrol which does the work of my app.

I need to have a variable number of my usercontrols on my form at once, the number is known at runtime.

I want each one to be full client width, and all controls to fill the window, equal size... eg. if there are two, then each are half the client height - if three, then each are one third of the client height.

And the layout should resize as the main window resizes. I don't want the user to be able to resize the controls other than by resizing the main window (so a split container is out)

I've tried to use the TableLayoutPanel to do this but when I set the GrowStyle property to TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows, and add my controls, the number of rows doesn't change.

Surely this layout scheme isn't hard to achieve? I can't seem to figure it out?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It the layout is simple to calculate then it gets to be pretty hard to make TLP pay off.  Which is a control that works very well in the designer but is pretty awkward when you have an unpredictable number of controls.

This will work fine as well, a lot less code and one less control to slow your UI down:

```
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < Controls.Count; ++ix) {
            int y1 = this.ClientSize.Height * ix / Controls.Count;
            int y2 = this.ClientSize.Height * (ix + 1) / Controls.Count;
            Controls[ix].Bounds = new Rectangle(0, y1, this.ClientSize.Width, y2-y1);
        }
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        OnResize(e);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: Since posting the question, I've come to a similar conclusion. My layout isn't complex and the custom code is not difficult. I'm suprised though, really, because although i'd never had cause to use TableLayoutPanel before, I was under the impression that this sort of thing was exactly what it did well - but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Table layout panel. in that each row height and width should be in percentage with equal to all rows. then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example using buttons to fill each cell of the TableLayoutPanel that is configured with 1 cell and a Row.SizeType = Percentage:

```
private int buttonCount = 0;

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button b = new Button() { Text = "Button #" + (++buttonCount).ToString() };
  b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

  if (buttonCount == 1) {
    tlp.Controls.Add(b, 0, 0);
  } else {
    tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle() { SizeType = SizeType.Percent });
    tlp.Controls.Add(b, 0, tlp.RowCount);
    tlp.RowCount++;
  }

  Single percHeight = ((Single)1 / (Single)tlp.RowStyles.Count) * 100;

  foreach (RowStyle rs in tlp.RowStyles) {
    rs.Height = percHeight;
  }
}
```

Every time you add a button (or a usercontrol) you recalculate the percentage height of each row.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I'd come up with something similar but I'm not really happy with it- it doesn't really seem any simpler than implementing manual layout code.